# mocha-webpack ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: webpack, mocha.js, mocha-webpack

I use NodeJS and mocha-webpack as a testing tool. Then I get an error in the terminal:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
...
```

I have in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "tws": "mocha-webpack -r ./test/test*.js",  
    "tw": "mocha-webpack --watch ./test/test*.js",
},
```

What is an issue and solution?

Answer (score 3):

I find a solution. It is necessary

1. to install jsdom-global:

   ```
   npm install jsdom-global
   ```
2. to change the package.json like this:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "tws": "mocha-webpack -r jsdom-global/register ./test/test*.js",    
       "tw": "mocha-webpack --watch -r jsdom-global/register ./test/test*.js",
   },
   ```